# PHP ~ How to test a fully associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

There is many - good and less good - ways to check associative arrays, but how would you check a "fully associative" array?

```
$john = array('name' => 'john', , 8 => 'eight', 'children' => array('fred', 'jane'));
$mary1 = array('name' => 'mary', 0 => 'zero', 'children' => array('jane'));
$mary2 = array('name' => 'mary', 'zero', 'children' => array('jane'));
```

Here $john is fully associative, $mary1 and $mary2 are not.

Comment: What do you mean with check associative arrays? You mean that all values have a specified key?

Comment: what do you mean "check"? do you want to know whether the array contains only associative keys? do you want to cycle through the associative array and check the values? i have no idea what you are asking here.

Comment: I don't see the difference between `$john` and `$mary1`.

Comment: You can't. Why is `$mary1` not associative? If it it is only because one key is `0` then just check whether `array_key_exists(0, $array)`. Or give a proper definition. What about `array( 0 => 0)`? And `array(1 => 1)`?

Comment: @alexn I believe AdeleK is looking for an `is_array()` for associative arrays.

Comment: @dqhendricks Not sure how you would better define "associative keys". But the key "8" from john is associative, both "0" from mary1 and 2 are not. Better?

Comment: And something else: If `array(1 => 1)` is associative, how would you distinguish it from `array_slice(array(0,1), 1)` ?

Comment: @AdeleK: And why is `0` not associative? It is explicit in `mary1`. I could understand for `mary2` but not for `mary1`.

Comment: @Felix Kling Not sure about the proper definition, that's why I used the "". By the way, there is no way - as far as I know - to distinguish $mary1 and $mary2....

Comment: @AdeleK I don't get the difference. a key that is a strictly numeric value is an index, while a key that is a string is associative. you cannot affect this with quotes either.

Comment: @AdeleK: So your definition is that an array is only associative if it can be distinguished from an array declared with non-associative elements?

Comment: meaning "8" is still an index, not an associative string.

Comment: An array with at least 1 string key is obviously an associative array. But what are the arrays with numeric keys only but with holes or even mixed string and integer keys?

Comment: @dqhendricks: Don't know where you got that from but that is not true. Proof: http://codepad.org/wi6cXMHj

Comment: you can cycle with a foreach checking each key making sure they are all in order.

Comment: @Felix Kling sorry, always thought that for some reason... not sure why. now deleted.

Comment: @dqhendricks: Maybe because of `mysql_fetch_array`? ;) (it  just combines both).

Comment: @Felix Kling ha yeah probably.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer Sure:-) but at least, $john is for now!

Comment: @AdeleK: you may find `$john` is not as "fully associative" as you thought.  The array auto-index value for any new values added to this array is now set at `9`.  Technically, Alin Purcaru is correct that there really is no difference between all the arrays.  Are you just trying to see if the key was not manually set?  If so, just check for the existence of key `0`.  Then again, `$mary1` would give same results as `$mary2`.

Comment: @Adelek: I think you want to start using SPL's ArrayObject, or similar SPL built-in type.  See: http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php.  Basically, these SPL types can mimic an array, while allowing you to run checks against keys/values as they are assigned (see `ArrayObject::offsetSet`).  At the end of all your checks, simply convert the final ArrayObject into a normal array if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

To make it short, you can't because every array is implemented the same way. From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> An array in PHP is actually an **ordered map**. A map is a type that associates values to keys.

If have no insight in the implementation, but I'm pretty sure that `array(1,2,3)` is just shorthand for `array(0=>1, 1=>2, 2=>3)`, i.e. in the end it is exactly the same. There is nothing with which you could distinguish that.

You could only *assume* that arrays created via `array(value, value,...)` have an index with `0` and the others have not. But you have already seen that this must not always be the case.

And every attempt to detect an "associative" array would fail at some point.

The actual question is: **Why** do you need this?

Comment: Why? Because I need to check some config arrays, and be sure they have been correctly set.

Comment: @AdeleK: What means correctly set in your case? How do you access the config array? If you just want to make sure that it contains only valid keys and every key is present, you can define an array with those keys and see whether `array_intersect($keys, array_keys($config))` is empty. Maybe it is better to actually state your problem than asking whether a possible solution would work ;) (but you should create a new question for that imo).

Comment: Somehow what I am already doing. And it seems I can't do better.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<?php
function is_assoc( $array ) {
    if( !is_array( $array ) || array_keys( $array ) == range( 0, count( $array ) - 1 ) ) {
        return( false );
    }
    foreach( $array as $value ) {
        if( is_array( $value ) && !is_assoc( $value ) ) {
            return( false );
        }
    }
    return( true );
}
?>
```

The detection depends on your definition of associative. This function checks for the associative that means arrays that don't have sequential numeric keys. Some may say that associative is anything where the key was implicitly set instead of calculated by php. Others may even define all PHP arrays as associative (in which case `is_array()` would have sufficed). Again, it all depends, but this is the function I use in my projects. Hopefully, it's good enough for you.

Comment: Sadly no. I am looking for a way to be sure the array is totally associative. I mean that all the keys have been defined and not any way automatically set, which has nothing to do with only string keys.

Comment: That's exactly what this function does. Keys that are "automatically set" by PHP default to numbers starting with 0. Granted this function returns false only when all of the keys in the array or any sub-arrays are sequential numeric starting with 0, but this the best you can get with the way PHP handles arrays. To my knowledge, there is no way to detect when associative key/value pairs are mixed in with values that have "automatically set keys."

Comment: To my knowledge either :-)  That's why I tried to come here and see how right or wrong I was.  Thanks